# Подскажите как запустить проект из google drive api?

Tags: android, google-drive

После запуска на **Android Studio** этого проекта [Google Drive api с официального проекта от google](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)
в **Genimotion** появилась ошибка следующего содержания:

```
"Google Drive Android API Demos won't run without Google Play services,
which are missing from your phone".
```

И ниже кнопка с названием:

```
"Get Google Play services",
```

на которую кликаешь и ничего не происходит.

*Как решить эту проблему? 
Можете расписать поподробнее как запустить этот проект, чтобы этот проект был работоспособным?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не запускается, так как на эмуляторах Genimotion из коробки не установлены Google Services.

3 пути:

1. Самое долгое. [Установить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) на этот эмулятор Google Services;
2. Использовать свежий нативный эмулятор. Создать его можно через 
   Android Studio;
3. Использовать реальное устройство с Google Services

Comment: Пробывал через устройство, после  того как выбрал пункт в listview появился диалог : выберите аккаунт для Google Drive Android API, я выбрал аккаунт и ничего не произошло.

Comment: @юрагибкин А что должно было произойти?

Comment: выполниться какой-то функционал . но приложение можно сказать просто зависает на авторизации

Comment: @юрагибкин а вы зарегистрировали свой ключ? 

В репозиториит сказано:
If you actually want to run this sample app (though it is mostly provided so you can read the code), you will need to register an OAuth 2.0 client for the package com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo with your own debug keys and set

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: я регистрировал только sh1

Comment: а все, прописал для этого приложения и все заработало,спасибо